# Automapper different Configuration

Tags: automapper

As suggested in this answer [Using Profiles in Automapper to map the same types with different logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183401/using-profiles-in-automapper-to-map-the-same-types-with-different-logic), can anybody provide an example of using Automapper with different Configuration object?
I need to have two or more configuration for mapping between two objects. How can I register many configuration objects and how to use them?

Comment: so y don't you just use the answer from that question ?

Comment: well, i didn't manage to build several configuration objects, and used CreateMap on them, all that with StructureMap for DI! I was hoping someone could give me code example, from where i could start.

Comment: @Hrvoje did you get some solution for keeping multiple mapping for same types?