# Multiple mappings for the same type using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper, dto

I need help with my **mapper** program.
i have two types (Lets say A and B)and i want to have two different mappings.
In one method i want to use the first mapping between A and B and in other method i want to take the second.

I saw that "Mapper" Class is static, so i can't use CreateMap twice.

Is this possible?

thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using the static `Mapper` class, you can create different instances of the underlying MappingEngine and configuration classes. Then you can configure the instances differently.

Update: see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183401/using-profiles-in-automapper-to-map-the-same-types-with-different-logic/2196854#2196854).