# Automapper maps correctly on first call but skips properties on second call

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, automapper

I have the following classes defined:

```cs
public class ImageIndexModel {
   public string Description {get; set;}
   public string InstrumentNumber {get; set;}
}

public class ImageEditModel : ImageIndexModel {
    public int TotalCount = 0;
}

public class Clerk {  //This is actually a class defined by LinqToSql
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public string InstrumentNo {get; set;}
}
```

Now, in my `global.asax`, I've defined the following Mapping in `Application_Start()`.

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<ImageIndexModel, Clerk>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.InstrumentNo,
              opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.InstrumentNumber));
```

Lastly, in one of my controllers, I have the following code:

```cs
var _existing = new Clerk();
var _default = new ImageEditModel() {
                 InstrumentNumber = "12345678", Description = "Test"
               };
Mapper.Map(_default, _existing);
```

The first time I call the Action on my controller and this mapping is run, everything works fine and the `InstrumentNumber` is correctly mapped to the `InstrumentNo` of the `Clerk` object.  However, the second time the Action gets called, `InstrumentNo` does not get mapped.  `InstrumentNumber` definitely has a value but `InstrumentNo` remains null.

Any ideas what might be happening here?

Comment: Your code, as entered in the question, works fine even when run multiple times.  So Automapper does not appear to be the problem.  I suspect something with the Linq2SQL-generated class or something with the way its being used in ASP.NET.  Without more code, its difficult to say what could be wrong.  I would set breakpoints inside the property setters of the linq2sql-generated classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once had the opposite problem, where too many mappings were happening.  It was resolved by calling mapper.reset() as described [here for potentially other reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365649/automapper-in-the-dal-when-to-use-mapper-reset).  Perhaps something else in your application is resetting your mapper out from underneath you such that it is no longer resolving mappings which you believe it should (and does for a short while)?  The key from the other question is that Automapper is singleton, and so another portion of your code can load or late-bind and foul it up without you knowing.