# Any suggestion to drive AutoMapper mapping through user-defined configuration?

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm finding a way to drive AutoMapper through user-defined configuration without changing codes.

For example, I want user-defined mapping definition like `Source.Property.SubProperty1 => Result.SubProperty` drives how AutoMapper maps during run time.

Appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you want to have several AutoMapper configurations, and then at runtimee decide programatically which configuration to use?

Comment: sorry friend but can't understand, could you clarify your goal please

Comment: @AndersNK Thanks for your time and checking my question.  Sorry that my question wasn't clear.  I updated it and hope it becomes better.  Yes, I am finding a way to have several AutoMapper configurations which will decide how it maps at run time.

Comment: @niceman  Thanks for your time and checking my question.  Hope you understand me through updated question and my reply to AndersNK.  I tried to reply to you both but I can only notify one user at a time here.

Comment: @PyitPhyoAung I see "I'm finding" could you put your effort in the question, and glad to help :)

Comment: This question (and answer) might be of interest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183401/using-profiles-in-automapper-to-map-the-same-types-with-different-logic

Comment: Thanks very much the link @AndersNK.  So far, I've tried to define, compile and generate dynamic mapping class for simple mapping definitions at runtime and to use that assembly to define AutoMapper mapping and it looks promising so far.  I'm exploring for more complex mapping categories like custom mapping.