# AutoMapper with different instances

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-6, automapper

I have two classes

```
public class PatientViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }        

    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

}
```

and

```
public class PatientExtended : PatientViewModel
{

    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public string IsActive { get; set; }

    public class IsActiveResolver : ValueResolver<bool, string>
    {
        protected override string ResolveCore(bool source)
        {
            return source ? "Active" : "InActive";
        }
    }
}
```

I  mapped entityframework **Patient** object with my custom class **PatientViewModel** successfully  in the following function. Its giving the expected result.

```
  private List<PatientExtended> GetPatientFromDB()
  {
        IList<Patient> patient = db.Patients.ToList();

        Mapper.CreateMap<Patient, PatientExtended>().ForMember(s =>s.IsActive,m => m.ResolveUsing<MvcWithAutoMapper.Models.PatientExtended.IsActiveResolver>().FromMember(x => x.IsActive));            

        IList<PatientExtended> patientViewItem =  Mapper.Map<IList<Patient>,IList<PatientExtended>>(patient);  

        return patientViewItem.ToList();
 }
```

Here, in the function I am getting list of patients with the status Active and Inactive.

Now, I am trying to get the details of a patient in the function

```
  public ActionResult Details(int id)
  {
        Patient patient = db.Patients.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();            

        Mapper.CreateMap<Patient, PatientExtended>().ForMember(dest => dest.IsActive, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.IsActive == true ? "Active" : "InActive")).ForMember(cv => cv.FullName, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.FirstName + " " + s.MiddleName + " " + s.LastName));

        patientViewItem = Mapper.Map<Patient, PatientExtended>(patient);

        return View(patientViewItem);
    }
```

Here, I am trying to get the **FullName** of the patient. But, its coming null. Then I added **.ForMember(cv => cv.FullName, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.FirstName + " " + s.MiddleName + " " + s.LastName));** in **GetPatientFromDB()** function 
**CreateMap** method and was able to get FullName in the second function.

Seems, **AutoMapper** work like static. Then in my scenario how can I create the 
different instances of **CreateMap** in different functions?
Because, at one place I want to have only **Status** and other place I want to 
have **Status** and **FullName** both.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: I follow the same kind of pattern but I create a specific view model for each type of view. Mapper.CreateMap<Patient, DetailsViewModel>. I personally don't think there's a way to do it the way you are thinking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Profiles in Automapper to map the same types with different logic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183401/using-profiles-in-automapper-to-map-the-same-types-with-different-logic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for reply friends. I found the solution. Before and after using AutoMapper, I reset the AutoMapper

```
    AutoMapper.Mapper.Reset();
```

and it worked.Refer this link
http://blog.cymen.org/2011/06/17/automapper-and-mapper-reset/