# AutoMapper exclude unwanted profiles

Tags: c#, automapper

I created a `PersonInsertDto` which inherits from `PersonDto` so that I could perform a unique mapping for inserts.

So my class looks like `public class PersonInsertDto : PersonDto`

I setup a profile with `CreateMap<PersonInsertDto, Person>()`, which maps differently than my profile `CreateMap<PersonDto, Person>()`

This works perfectly when converting from `PersonInsertDto` to `Person`. However, my insert profile is also being ran when converting from the plain `PersonDto` to `Person`.

How can I make sure that AutoMapper only runs the `PersonDto` => `Person` profile?

*AutoMapper version 6.2.2.0*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Profiles in Automapper to map the same types with different logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183401/using-profiles-in-automapper-to-map-the-same-types-with-different-logic)